# Ability to receive files with the MS bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I might be a bit early on this, but is it somehow possible to also receive files (mainly via Skype) with the new Microsoft Bot Framework?
I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found `IList<Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Attachment> Attachments` in `Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Message` class.

```
foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments)
{
    var content = attachment.Content; // I think the content of uploaded file here.
}
```

No documentation though, sad.

---

**UPDATE (April 01, 2016)**

I did a quick testing with the emulator

You can clearly see what the response from the API in the emulator.

[image: Attachments]

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: First download attachment by using contentUrl. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45372844/1737819

Answer (score 3):

You can find some documentation on attachments here:

http://docs.botframework.com/connector/message-content/#attachments

[image]

You can also use the "ChannelData" field to take advantage of some of the special features offered by Email and Slack:

http://docs.botframework.com/connector/custom-channeldata/