# How to read attachment content from bot framework C#?

Tags: c#, excel, bots, attachment, botframework

I am writing a bot and expecting the user to send me an attachment, which I want to read and translate into objects.

I have the following code so far:

```
if (message.Attachments != null && message.Attachments.Any())
{
    var attachment = message.Attachments.First();
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        if ((message.ChannelId.Equals("skype", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || message.ChannelId.Equals("msteams", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) && new Uri(attachment.ContentUrl).Host.EndsWith("skype.com"))
        {
            var token = await new MicrosoftAppCredentials().GetTokenAsync();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        }

        var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(attachment.ContentUrl); 
        var contentLenghtBytes = responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength; // this is populated correctly

        if(attachment.Name.ToLower().Equals("opportunity.xlsx"))
        {
            var temp = attachment.Content; // This Content is always null, even though everything else is populated.
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can suggest how can I read the attachment xlsx content please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The attachment is not available in the `Content` property. You first need to download the attachment using the `ContentUrl` and then perform whatever you want, using the response message after downloading the file.

Take a look at the [Receive-Attachments](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-ReceiveAttachment) C# sample.

```
public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
{
    var message = await argument;

    if (message.Attachments != null && message.Attachments.Any())
    {
        var attachment = message.Attachments.First();
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Skype & MS Teams attachment URLs are secured by a JwtToken, so we need to pass the token from our bot.
            if ((message.ChannelId.Equals("skype", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || message.ChannelId.Equals("msteams", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
                && new Uri(attachment.ContentUrl).Host.EndsWith("skype.com"))
            {
                var token = await new MicrosoftAppCredentials().GetTokenAsync();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            }

            var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(attachment.ContentUrl);

            var contentLenghtBytes = responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

            await context.PostAsync($"Attachment of {attachment.ContentType} type and size of {contentLenghtBytes} bytes received.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Hi there! I'm a bot created to show you how I can receive message attachments, but no attachment was sent to me. Please, try again sending a new message including an attachment.");
    }

    context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

Comment: sorry, but how is this different from my code snippet above?

Comment: You are doing attachment.Content which is wrong. Since you are downloading the attachment, you should use responseMessage.Content to access the file

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some other dll to read the excel data, if that is what you mean. Do u mean to read the contents of the excel file after it has been uploded then you could  use https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader